# Rally 2 SDK and confluence integration

Tags: rally, confluence

What's the best way to embed a rally app inside a confluence document?

I tried pasting my code between {html} macros but it doesn't work

```
{html}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Grid Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p4/sdk.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Rally.onReady(function() {
        Ext.define('CustomApp', {
            extend: 'Rally.app.App',
            componentCls: 'app',

            launch: function() {
                ...
                ...
            }
        });
    Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
            name: 'Grid Example'
        });
    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
</style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>

{html}
```

The above code works fine when opened directly, but doesn't display anything when pasted inside confluence's {html} macro. (I am logged into rally in another tab)

Comment: I think there is a setting for the HTML plugin for whether or not to parse <head> content.  Is this enabled?

Comment: I would put all of that code in an external html document and then display it in your confluence page via an html-include macro. Let us know if that works.

Comment: @Kyle: Normal javascript works fine when placed inside <head>, so I guess it is enabled.

Comment: @Sullivan: the html-include macro is disabled for our confluence ( possibly for security reasons), so I'm not able to try that.

Answer (score 1):

A work around is to host the html page on a server and include it in an {iframe} macro in confluence. However some browsers might have cross-domain related security issues.

Finally I decided not to render the content inside my confluence page. I just hosted the html page on a server and added a link to it in my confluence page.

Comment: Vikram, sorry this went un-answered. This is a common need for Rally customers. I'm not sure why your session credentials from a second browser tab didn't allow confluence to render. Nonetheless, ultimately you'll need some sort of encoded read-only credentials to embed your App in confluence to avoid viewers of the report getting prompted to login to Rally.

Comment: In AppSDK 1 - Rally has LoginKey to support this functionality. A LoginKey-like functionality is on the roadmap for AppSDK2, however, I don't have an estimate for when it may become available.

Comment: I've been using the LoginKey till now. I just shifted to SDK 2 and was looking for an alternative. Glad to know that it's on the roadmap. I'll continue using my workaround till then.